# How to show coordinate on the polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, layouts, grids-graticules

[image: how to it]

I try to set and go to search by help GIS but I couldn't find an answer

How to show coordinate on the polygon but I don't show it on dataframe

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to include another graphic that shows what you are trying to see, please?  I'm assuming that you do not want the labelling to follow your graphic clip extent like in your current graphic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what it is you're asking.  If you want the coordinates of the vertices, you'll have to create a point layer from your vertices.  However, to me, it looks like you wan the grid/graticule coordinates to be displayed on your polygon, instead of the edge of the dataframe.

If you want the graticule labels to display like in your image, Go to your Data Frame Properties and click the Data Frame Tab.  Under Clip Options select "Clip to shape" and choose the polygon layer under "Specify Shape".  Then tick the box that says "Clip Grids and Graticules".

[image]

I have created an example with and without the clip options.

### Without Clip Options

(note the graticule on the border of the image)
[image]

### With Clip Options

(note the graticule on the edge of the polygon)
[image]

In my daily workflow, I can't see a need for this.  It's common practice to have the coordinates on the edge of the map.  Also, it looks like it give mixed results (putting latitude and longitude next to each other).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Create a point layer by the point of which coordinate you want to show, then add X,Y field and calculate geometry in decimal degrees.Go to XY tool to add callouts then modify this callout by double click as the shot below-
[image: shot]